# images cannot show

Tags: java, android

[image]

![enter image description here][2]

I tried to make a CRUD and load images to the mysql server using Android Studio ... CRUD went smoothly but the images cannot show ...

I use the reference link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8ylPtpOCdk

Download link: 
https://github.com/haerulmuttaqin/MyPets-App

code :

```
  void readMode(){

        mName.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        mSpecies.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        mBreed.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        mName.setFocusable(false);
        mSpecies.setFocusable(false);
        mBreed.setFocusable(false);

        mGenderSpinner.setEnabled(false);
        mBirth.setEnabled(false);

        mFabChoosePic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    private void editMode(){

        mName.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mSpecies.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mBreed.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        mGenderSpinner.setEnabled(true);
        mBirth.setEnabled(true);

        mFabChoosePic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating Action Button was moved to another package. You can use `.show()` and `.hide()` instead.

```
mFabChoosePic.show()
mFabChoosePic.hide()
```